# Pandas: group some data

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
         date   id
0  12-12-2015  123
1  13-12-2015  123
2  15-12-2015  123
3  16-12-2015  123
4  18-12-2015  123
5  10-12-2015  456
6  13-12-2015  456
7  15-12-2015  456
```

And I want to get

```
      id   date   count
0  123   10-12-2015   0
1  123   11-12-2015   0
2  123   12-12-2015   1
3  123   13-12-2015   1
4  123   14-12-2015   0
5  123   15-12-2015   1
6  123   16-12-2015   1
7  123   17-12-2015   0
8  123   18-12-2015   1
9  456   10-12-2015   1
10  456   11-12-2015   0
11  456   12-12-2015   0
12 456   13-12-2015   1
13  456   14-12-2015   0
14 456   15-12-2015   1
```

I try before

```
df = df.groupby('id').resample('D').size().reset_index(name='val')
```

But it search date between existing to every `id`. How can I do it to some period?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? do you want to group it by id and date and count the number of elements in the group?

Comment: @dleal I want to group it by id and next specify the interval to use `resample('D')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by reindexing in the aggregation of each group and filling `NaN`s with `0`.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
date   id
0  12-12-2015  123
1  13-12-2015  123
2  15-12-2015  123
3  16-12-2015  123
4  18-12-2015  123
5  10-12-2015  456
6  13-12-2015  456
7  15-12-2015  456""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d-%m-%Y")

startdate = df['date'].min()
enddate = df['date'].max()
alldates = pd.date_range(startdate, enddate, freq='D', name='date')

def process_id(g):
    return g.resample('D').size().reindex(alldates).fillna(0)

output = (df.set_index('date')
            .groupby('id')
            .apply(process_id)
            .stack()
            .rename('val')
            .reset_index('id'))

print(output)

#              id  val
# date                
# 2015-12-10  123  0.0
# 2015-12-11  123  0.0
# 2015-12-12  123  1.0
# 2015-12-13  123  1.0
# 2015-12-14  123  0.0
# 2015-12-15  123  1.0
# 2015-12-16  123  1.0
# 2015-12-17  123  0.0
# 2015-12-18  123  1.0
# 2015-12-10  456  1.0
# 2015-12-11  456  0.0
# 2015-12-12  456  0.0
# 2015-12-13  456  1.0
# 2015-12-14  456  0.0
# 2015-12-15  456  1.0
# 2015-12-16  456  0.0
# 2015-12-17  456  0.0
# 2015-12-18  456  0.0
```

Comment: How can I return date only with month and year? I change `alldates = pd.date_range(startdate, enddate, freq='M', name='filtered_date')` but it return `'2013-12-31', '2014-01-31', '2014-02-28', '2014-03-31', ...`

Comment: `output = (df.set_index('date')
            .groupby('id')
            .apply(process_id)
            .stack()
            .rename('val')
            .reset_index('id'))` return `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: @ldevyataykina: Can we discuss this in chat? Join me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117232/pandas-group-some-data)